# Undefined index: cnt

Tags: php, request, undefined

> ```
> Showing error as undefined index cnt.
> ```
>
> please help me regarding this issue.thanks in adcance

```
if($_REQUEST["cnt"]!=""){   
       $count=$_REQUEST["cnt"];     
       $cntprev=$count-2;    
    }else    
      {      
        $count=1; 
      }
```

Comment: Did you put cnt in your get variables when you requested the page? Did you try `if (!empty($_REQUEST['cnt']))` ?

Comment: no..can u tell me clearly please i am a beginner

Comment: if(isset($_REQUEST["cnt"]) && $_REQUEST["cnt"]!="") { $count=$_REQUEST["cnt"];
$cntprev=$count-2; } else { $count=1; }

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the index is set. Actually you just check if it is an empty string. But you have to check if it is set, not empty and the value is numeric (if you want to cat it to int float ...). This should work:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["cnt"]) && !empty($_REQUEST["cnt"]) && is_numeric($_REQUEST["cnt"])) {
    $count=$_REQUEST["cnt"];
    $cntprev=$count-2; 
} else { 
        $count=1; 
}
```

Comment: its showing error as undefined variable col  

$res = mysql_query("select * from book order by no desc $limit");
   while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
    $position=21; // Define how many character you want to display.
    $message=$result['title'];
    $post = substr($message, 0, $position);
     $col++;

Comment: @userds I don't understand your comment. isn't it an other question, and have nothing todo the undefined index? (but if you get an undefined variable error, you have to define your variable before the while loop like `$col = 0;`)